Shape not playing animation when its text is changed with VBA
I am trying to play a simple pulse animation on shape click also toggle its display text. As long as you are not changing the shape text there is no issue with the shape animation and VBA also Works. But as soon as I am interacting with shape text it will change text once(animation won't work at all) and then neither VBA nor animation will work.
My code.
Sub updatetext(shp As Shape)


If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "aa" Then
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "bb"
Else
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "aa"
End If


End Sub

I tried putting shape below the current shape and making above shape transparent but still the pulse animation doesn't work
